# Why do trait object vtables contain size and alignment?

Tags: dynamic, rust, vtable

Rust's trait objects are fat pointers that contain 2 regular pointers: to data and to a vtable. The vtable is a structure containing a destructor function pointer, all trait method pointers and finally the size and alignment of the data.

**What are the size and alignment fields for?**

I couldn't find much:

- [Blog post A](https://huonw.github.io/blog/2015/01/peeking-inside-trait-objects/): it's for deallocating memory, but not used today, may be used by some future, more flexible mechanisms (What could it be? Does any exist yet?)
- [Blog post B](https://iandouglasscott.com/2018/05/28/exploring-rust-fat-pointers/): it's for deallocating type-erased boxed values, so they know how to release memory (Doesn't `Box` store location, size and alignment of its allocation? Every size variant of every DST can't get its own version of a vtable, can it?)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's what I've found so far:

The size & alignment properties in a vtable are loaded in the [`librustc_codegen_llvm::glue::size_and_align_of_dst()`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/b75b0471a8b87c44e0bd953d2a5c36d896128723/src/librustc_codegen_llvm/glue.rs#L25) function which returns the size and alignment of a dynamically sized type. For `ty::Dynamic(..)` values (the compiler's internal way of describing trait objects), the size and alignment are read from the vtable:

```
match t.sty {
    ty::Dynamic(..) => {
        // load size/align from vtable
        let vtable = info.unwrap();
        (meth::SIZE.get_usize(bx, vtable), meth::ALIGN.get_usize(bx, vtable))
    }
    ...
}
```

This function in turn is used in several places:

- [`librustc_codegen_llvm::operand::store_unsized()`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/b355906919927ab3c879becd14392f023af883a1/src/librustc_codegen_llvm/mir/operand.rs#L331) for allocating enough storage space on the stack for the storing the unboxed value.
- [`librustc_codegen_llvm::intrinsic::codegen_intrinsic_call()`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/b75b0471a8b87c44e0bd953d2a5c36d896128723/src/librustc_codegen_llvm/intrinsic.rs#L152) for implementing the [`size_of_val()` intrinsic](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/intrinsics/fn.size_of_val.html)
- [`librustc_codegen_llvm::intrinsic::codegen_intrinsic_call()`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/b75b0471a8b87c44e0bd953d2a5c36d896128723/src/librustc_codegen_llvm/intrinsic.rs#L166) for implementing the [`min_align_of_val()` intrinsic](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/intrinsics/fn.min_align_of_val.html)

I didn't spot any places where these values are currently fed into the Rust deallocation function ([`__rust_dealloc()`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/727eabd68143e968d8826ee29b8ea7792d29fa96/src/liballoc/alloc.rs#L28)), but they could certainly be used for that in the future.

Comment: Likely for forwards compatibility.

Comment: @PeterHall Yes. Knowing the size & alignment of data is so fundamental & useful, there's little reason not to include it especially given that the storage overhead is once per type-vtable and it's just two `usize`s.

Comment: Thank you for such a comprehensive answer! I have 1 more question: [Rustonomicon states](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/exotic-sizes.html) that DSTs pretty much boil down to slices. Slices have size unknown at compilation time. How do vtables handle size field of slices with different lengths? Does slice of 2 `u32`s have other vtable from slice of 3 `u32`s? After all one has size of 16 and other has 24 (simplification).

Comment: @CodeSandwich The Rustonomicon might be being unclear. There are certain DSTs which resemble slices - structs with a few sized fields then a slice (or other DST) as the final field. A pointer to any DST has to carry extra information in the form of an extra `usize`. For slices, or slice-like DSTs, the extra information is the size of the slice. For trait objects, it's a pointer to the vtable.

Comment: So that's why it's not possible to cast different trait objects, slice objects and composed DSTs to trait objects.